# word2vec for dictionary of words

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, word2vec

I need to generate word2vec array for a dictionary of words. The dictionary looks something like this

```
test={0: 'tench, Tinca tinca',
 1: 'goldfish, Carassius auratus',
 2: 'great white shark, white shark, man-eater, man-eating shark, Carcharodon carcharias',
 3: 'tiger shark, Galeocerdo cuvieri',
 4: 'hammerhead, hammerhead shark'}
```

The loop should go through each line, check if the word exists in the model, if yes then store the vector in an array otherwise check the next word in the line. If none of the words are present in the gensim model, then it should do nothing (array is initialised with zeros)
However if a word doesn't exist in the pre trained model, then it raises this exception:

> KeyError: "word 'Galeocerdo cuvieri' not in vocabulary"

What should be the ideal loop that also has the exception in order to bypass the error raised?
This is my starting code:

```
 import gensim
 model = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('/home/shikhar /Downloads/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin',binary=True) 
 array=np.zeros((4,300)) 
 for i in test:
     synonyms=test[i].split(',')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't try this

```
vectors= list()
for i in test:
    flag=True
    synonyms=test[i].split(',')
    for k in synonyms:
        try:
            vectors.append(model[k]])
            flag = False
            break
        except KeyError as e:
            print(e)
            continue
    if flag:
        vectors.append(# Insert your array with zeroes here)
```

I'm assuming that you need all the vectors in a list

Comment: Thanks for the help! It is what I want, except that I want only 1 word from a line (synonyms) and want it to move to the next line as soon as it gets that vector. Can you help me with that?